# True or false: If you square the coefficients in the expansion of $(x+1)^n$, the resulting polynomial has $n$ distinct real roots.

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, roots

It seems that if you square the coefficients in the expansion of $(x+1)^n$, the resulting polynomial has $n$ distinct real roots. (I experimented using desmos.com.)

In other words, I am looking for a proof (or counter-example) for the proposition that polynomial $\displaystyle p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2x^k$ has exactly $n$ distinct real roots.

But I have not found a proof. I tried induction, to no avail.

(Context: I am looking for an expanded polynomial with exactly, say, $100$ distinct real roots.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127387/discussion-on-question-by-dan-true-or-false-if-you-square-the-coefficients-in-t).

Answer (score 3):

We have $p(x) = (1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ where $P_n$ is the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$. This [follows from the Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Rodrigues%27_formula_and_other_explicit_formulas), among other ways. (Mathematica spotted it for me.) The Legendre polynomials are orthogonal polynomials, so by standard theory their roots interlace each other, and in particular $P_n(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots. Moreover it is easy to see $-1$ is not a root.

The function $x \mapsto \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is bijective from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ to $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$. Hence the $n$ distinct roots of $P_n$ are hit by $n$ distinct values in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$, so $p(x)$ has at least, hence exactly, $n$ distinct real roots.

Comment: Wow, that was amazing.

Comment: (Now I see @TeresaLisbon gave the same argument in the rather extended comments discussion on the main post.)

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Thanks , yes , I knew it would be the case. We can try a standalone argument, but it seems that is not required now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I briefly considered doing just that--making a completely self-contained argument--but moments later it proved too tedious for me to bother. If anybody wants to do so, they're welcome to edit my answer or post their own.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson True, it was too tedious!

Comment: Thank you, Joshua.

Answer (score 1):

NOT A FULL ANSWER
$$p_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=0} {n\choose k}^2x^k$$
for a polynomial to have a triple root, we need $p'$ and $p$ to share a factor:
$$p_n'(x) = \sum^n_{k=0} {n\choose k}^2\cdot k\cdot x^{k-1}$$
$$p_n'(x) = \sum^n_{k=0} {n\choose k}^2\cdot \frac{k}{n}\cdot n\cdot x^{k-1}$$
Note that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{k} {n-1 \choose k-1}$
$$p_n'(x) = n\sum^n_{k=0} {n-1\choose k-1}{n\choose k}x^{k-1} =n\sum^n_{k=0} {n-1\choose k-1}({n-1 \choose k}+{n-1 \choose k-1})x^{k-1}=np_{n-1}(x)+ n\sum^n_{k=0} {n-1\choose k-1}{n-1\choose k}x^{k-1}$$
$$\overbrace{np_n(x)}^{\text{multiple of } p_n}-nx^n+n\sum^n_{k=0} {n-1\choose k-1}{n-1\choose k}x^{k-1}$$

Comment: You lost a factor of $n/k$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

$$p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}^2 x^{k-1}\cdot \frac{n^2x}{k^2}$$

So to relate this to $p_{n-1}$, we need to differentiate, multiply by $x$, and differentiate:

$$(xp_n'(x))' = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom {n-1}k^2 x^k n^2 = n^2 p_{n-1}(x)$$

So $p'_n(x) + xp''_n(x) = n^2 p_{n-1}(x)$. We can pack this up into a generating function:

$$P(x,y) = \sum_{n}p_n(x) y^n.$$

And $P_x + x P_{xx} = P_y + y P_{yy}$, which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very well polished, and seems to contain some errors. But I believe it is workable into a complete proof.

We want to let one term dominate all the others.

$\binom nk^2 x^k \over \binom {n}{k-1}^2 x^{k-1}$ is equal to $(\frac{n-k+1}{k})^2x$. Dub $a_k = \binom nk^2 x^k$. Then $a_{k-1} : a_k : a_{k+1} = \frac{k^2}{(n-k+1)^2x}:1:\frac{(n-k)^2x}{(k+1)^2}$.

By letting $x = -\frac{(k+1)k}{(n-k)(n-k+1)}$, $a_{k-1} : a_k : a_{k+1}$ becomes $\frac{kn - k^2}{1-k^2 + nk + n} : -1 : \frac{kn - k^2}{1-k^2 + nk + n}$. So $a_k$ is greater than the neighboring terms in absolute value. An easy inspection now shows that the terms before and after $a_k$ form two alternating series, whose absolute values are decreasing. Therefore $\sum_{i < k} a_i$ and $\sum_{i>k} a_i$ are both less than $a_k\frac{kn - k^2}{1-k^2 + nk + n}$ in terms of absolute value.

We just have to refine our estimations a little bit. Indeed, the alternating series $\sum_{i>k}a_i$ can be grouped as $a_{k+1} + (a_{k+2} + a_{k+3}) + (a_{k+4}+a_{k+5}) +\dots$. We closely inspect this series

$(a_{k+2} + a_{k+3}) + (a_{k+4}+a_{k+5}) +\dots = a_{k+2} + (a_{k+3} + a_{k+4}) + (a_{k+5}+a_{k+6}) +\dots$,

But $|a_{k+2} + a_{k+3}| > |a_{k+3} + a_{k+4}|$, etc. We get $\left|\sum_{i > k+1} a_i\right| > \frac12 |a_{k+2}|$. This allows us to state

$$\left|\sum_{i>k} a_i\right| < |a_{k+1}| - \frac12 |a_{k+2}|$$

So $p\left(-\frac{(k+1)k}{(n-k)(n-k+1)}\right) = \mathrm{sgn}(a_k) \left(|a_k| - |a_{k+1}| - |a_{k-1}| + \frac12 |a_{k+2}| + \frac12 |a_{k-2}| \right)$. And it turns out that the stuff in the parentheses is positive. So It has the same sign as $a_k$.

The above choice for $x$ should (?) also work for $k=0,1,n-1,n$. So summing up, for each $k$, we have a choice of $x$ such that $p(x)$ has the same sign as $a_k$, which is just $(-1)^k$. And note that the $n+1$ choices of $x$ are increasing. Hence, we have $n$ alternation of signs of $p(x)$. So $p(x)$ has $n$ roots.

Comment: Sadly, there is a major flaw: the estimation of $|a_{k+2}+a_{k+3}|$ is not correct, sometimes $|\sum_{i>k+1}a_i| < \frac12|a_{k+2}|$...